# i want to play music from webSite with the Mediaelement ," media.setSource()"

Tags: windows-phone-7

i get the stream from webSite ,then put it  in  isolatedStorage into IsolatedstorageStream ,

but it don't work ,no error no sound , what's wrong ????

```
HttpWebResponse reponse = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{

   Stream stream=reponse.GetResponseStream();
   SaveMusic(stream, "music");
   ReadMusic("music");
   Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
       () =>
       {
           me.AutoPlay = true;
           me.Volume = 100;
           me.SetSource(songStream);
           me.Play();
      });

}
```

Comment: Please note that remote music playback won't actually work if you're connected with Zune, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2010/10/26/quick-tip-using-the-wp-connect-utility-instead-of-zune-client-windows-phone-7.aspx for a alternative way to connect the device.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `saving` and `reading` code is correct, your `stream's position` might be at the end. Try adding

```
songStream.Position = 0;
```

before `SetSource(songStream);`

Try using this to save the file:

```
 using (var fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
 { 
        var buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        using (var myIsStream = fileStorage.OpenFile("Source\\Music\\" + name + ".mp3", FileMode.CreateNew)) 
        { 
              int bytesRead = 0; 
              while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) 
              myIsStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
        } 
 }
```

Comment: ye i will have a try ,thanks but there was anonther question  an error show " Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream"

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks keyboardP  for your help ;here is my code

```
protected void SaveMusic(Stream stream,string name)
{

            IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!fileStorage.DirectoryExists("Source/Music"))
            {
                fileStorage.CreateDirectory("Source/Music");
            }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile("Source\\Music\\" + name + ".mp3", FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }

}
protected void ReadMusic(string name)
{

        using (IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            songStream = null;
            songStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Source\\Music\\" + name + ".mp3", FileMode.Open, fileStorage);                  

        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with a different way of saving the MP3 file to the Isolated Storage. Try using that code.